# Why doesn't the iframe inherit the style of the parent?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I want my iframe to be styled in the same way as the parent. Which is not happening here, as "Thank you" should be in white.

[image: h1 colour mismatch]

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kognise/water.css@latest/dist/dark.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h1>
Hello!
</h1>

<iframe src=https://s.natalian.org/2020-02-16/thank-you.html></iframe>
```

I noticed https://stackoverflow.com/a/22011242/4534 which claims it need to be on the same domain, however on my own site: https://dabase.com/ with the iframe as `<iframe frameBorder="0" src="https://subscribe.dabase.com/"></iframe>` still appears unstyled!

What am I missing?

Comment: looks like a duplicate of the following post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612374/iframe-inherit-from-parent

Comment: I don't want to run Javascript to fix this problem ...